# How to Expand ( Increase the size of Container ) the particular container on clicked in flutter

Tags: list, flutter, animation, containers, expandable

- Container Size depends on the widget's child length
- I want all things in the mobile screen height not the inner child scroll or outer

**I expected output like below -**

[image]

**what I am getting -**

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ExpandableContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExpandableContainer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ExpandableContainer> createState() => _ExpandableContainerState();
}

class _ExpandableContainerState extends State<ExpandableContainer> {
  int selectedIndex = -1;
  List dataList = [
    {
      "title": "Title 1",
      "items": [
        'Item 1',
        'Item 2',
        'Item 3',
        'Item 4',
      ],
    },
    {
      "title": "Title 2",
      "items": [
        "Item 1",
        "Item 2",
        "Item 3",
        "Item 4",
        "Item 5",
        "Item 6",
        "Item 7",
        "Item 8",
      ],
    },
    {
      "title": "Title 3",
      "items": [
        "Item 1",
        "Item 2",
        "Item 3",
        "Item 4",
      ],
    },
    {
      "title": "Title 4",
      "items": [
        "Item 1",
        "Item 2",
        "Item 3",
        "Item 4",
        "Item 5",
        "Item 6",
        "Item 7",
        "Item 8",
        "Item 9",
        "Item 10",
      ],
    },
    {
      "title": "Title 5",
      "items": [
        "Item 1",
        "Item 2",
        "Item 3",
        "Item 4",
        "Item 5",
        "Item 6",
        "Item 7",
      ],
    },
  ];

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SizedBox(
        height: size.height,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: List.generate(
            dataList.length,
            (index) => GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => setState(() {
                selectedIndex = index;
              }),
              child: Container(
                height: size.height / dataList.length,
                width: size.width,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(32.0, 16.0, 0.0, 16.0),
                // alignment: Alignment.center,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  border: Border.all(width: 8.0, color: Colors.grey),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      dataList[index]["title"].toUpperCase(),
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 38.0,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                        letterSpacing: -2.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    for (var item in dataList[index]["items"])
                      Text(
                        selectedIndex == index ? item : "",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          height: selectedIndex == index ? 1.5 : 0.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What you see in that GIF is `ExpansionTile`, use it instead of a container.

Comment: An AnimatedList could solve your case.

Comment: @barotia sorry but not working

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
     List<String> category = [
        "HealthCare",
        "Food & Drink",
        "Beauty",
        "Baby & kids",
        "Homeware"
      ];
      List<Color> color = [
        Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        Colors.green.shade700,
        Colors.pinkAccent.shade100,
        Colors.blueAccent,
        Colors.amber,
      ];
      List<Color> textColor = [
        Colors.blueAccent.shade700,
        Colors.amber,
        Colors.pinkAccent.shade700,
        Colors.pinkAccent.shade100,
        Colors.white,
      ];
    
      int? selectedIndex;
      List<dynamic> dataList = [
        {
          "title": "Title 1",
          "items": [
            'Item 1',
            'Item 2',
            'Item 3',
            'Item 4',
          ],
        },
        {
          "title": "Title 2",
          "items": [
            "Item 1",
            "Item 2",
            "Item 3",
            "Item 4",
            "Item 5",
            "Item 6",
            "Item 7",
            "Item 8",
          ],
        },
        {
          "title": "Title 3",
          "items": [
            "Item 1",
            "Item 2",
            "Item 3",
            "Item 4",
          ],
        },
        {
          "title": "Title 4",
          "items": [
            "Item 1",
            "Item 2",
            "Item 3",
            "Item 4",
            "Item 5",
            "Item 6",
            "Item 7",
            "Item 8",
            "Item 9",
            "Item 10",
          ],
        },
        {
          "title": "Title 5",
          "items": [
            "Item 1",
            "Item 2",
            "Item 3",
            "Item 4",
            "Item 5",
            "Item 6",
            "Item 7",
          ],
        },
      ];

 Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: [
          ...category.map(
            (index) => Expanded(
              flex: selectedIndex==category.indexOf(index) ? (dataList[category.indexOf(index)]["items"].length/3).ceil(): 1,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  print(dataList[category.indexOf(index)]["items"].toString());
                  print("tap");
                  setState(() {
                    selectedIndex = category.indexOf(index);
                  });
                },
                child: Container(
                  color: color[category.indexOf(index)],
                  child: Center(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

                      children: [
                        Text(
                          index.toUpperCase(),
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 36,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: textColor[category.indexOf(index)]),
                        ),
                        selectedIndex == category.indexOf(index)
                            ? Column(
                                children: [
                                  ...dataList[category.indexOf(index)]
                                          ["items"]
                                      .map(
                                    (e) => Text(e),

                                  ),
                                  // ListTile(title:Text(dataList[category.indexOf(index)]["items"].toString()))
                                ],
                              )
                            : SizedBox(),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Just for small change use Expanded - Flex - flex: selectedIndex == index ? 0 : 1, so that expand the container depends on childs widget, and second things animation remain

Answer (score 0):

Please use ExpansionTile for expansion

```
              ExpansionTile(
                      iconColor:Colors.blue,
                      textColor:Colors.black,
                      title:  Text('Privacy Policy',style:  TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),

                      children: [
                        ListTile(
                          title:  Text('item1',textAlign: justifyText,),
                        ),

                        ListTile(
                          title:  Text('item2',textAlign: justifyText,),
                        ),


                        ListTile(
                          title:  Text('item3',textAlign: justifyText,),
                        ),


                        ListTile(
                          title:  Text('item4',textAlign: justifyText,),
                        ),

                      ],
                    ),
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but this is not working for my scenario

Answer (score 0):

Try this you can test this on dartpad its so now the one is hindering the size was on the container so if you select a certain index make the container height to null so that it will wrap the results inside.

```
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SizedBox(
        child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: dataList.length,
          itemBuilder:(context,index)
          =>GestureDetector(
              onTap:(){
                setState((){
                 selectedIndex = index;
                 print( dataList[index]['items'].map((e)=> e).toList());
                });
              },
              child: Container(
                 height:  selectedIndex == index ? null 
                  : size.height / dataList.length,
                width: size.width,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(32.0, 16.0, 0.0, 16.0),
                // alignment: Alignment.center,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  border: Border.all(width: 8.0, color: Colors.grey),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      dataList[index]["title"].toUpperCase(),
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 38.0,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                        letterSpacing: -2.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    
                      ...dataList[index]['items'].map((e)=> 
                      selectedIndex == index ?
                        Text(
                        e,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          height: selectedIndex == index ? 1.5 : 0.0,
                        ) ,
                      ) : Container(),).toList()
                    
                    
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            
          ),
          ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: i don't want to scrollable inner or outer child and fit to the screen all content

Answer (score 0):

**Solution No 1**

[image]

To achieve this you can use ExpansionTile class,

This widget is typically used with ListView to create an "expand / collapse" list entry. When used with scrolling widgets like ListView, a unique PageStorageKey must be specified to enable the ExpansionTile to save and restore its expanded state when it is scrolled in and out of view.

this is the link about ExpansionTile

[https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html#:~:text=ExpansionTile%20class%20Null%20safety,expand%20%2F%20collapse%22%20list%20entry](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html#:%7E:text=ExpansionTile%20class%20Null%20safety,expand%20%2F%20collapse%22%20list%20entry).

and this is the demo example link how to do it

https://rrtutors.com/tutorials/Expandable-Listview-Flutter-ExpansionTile

**Solution No 2**

*Use ExpandableGroup*

[image]

To achieve this you can use ExpandableGroup

this is the link about ExpandableGroup

https://pub.dev/packages/expandable_group

if you don't want to use plugin , just inspect this plugin code , it has simple logic

Comment: i dont want to scrollable all things, see what i expected output image

Answer (score 0):

You can use expansion tile but if the existing expansion tile does not provide the view required for your project, you can create your own custom expansion tile widget.

Like

[app_expansion_tile](https://gist.github.com/abhishekthakur0/c3da4260f44d68861056c934e8259c8b)

Answer (score -1):

You should use expansion tile, as far as i have saw in your image you don't want it to be scrollablle, what i suggest is to make a limitation on the expansiontile class or the child, then set restriction limit to with and height and make it be responsive.